# Как сделать интерактивную таблицу

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте :)
В общем цель такая - есть некая таблица (для простоты - пусть будет таблица Менделеева), нужно сделать так, чтобы при наведении мыши на элемент, выше таблицы отображалась некоторая краткая информация об элементе (в нашем случае - название хим. элемента, масса и т.д.) Наводишь мышь на другой элемент - другая информация. 
Вопрос о том, как хранить информацию. 
Информация в бд, из бд её берёт PHP и отправляет в массив JS. Это рационально? Просто тогда вся информация будет в html странице. А если её много? Что делать?

Comment: смотря что значит много. для таблицы менделеева это немного, к тому-же можно хранить данные по таблице в кэширующимся файле json например а не возвращать каждый раз с пом-ю php.

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов масса, если пару строчек на элемент, то
Можно хранить прям в ячейке в скрытом блоке: http://jsfiddle.net/jK5eB/

Answer (score 0):

Ну если информации много что можно было бы сделать так.
Каждой ячейки присвоить ID. При наведении подгружать информацию в div сверху с помощью ajax.

[AJAX](http://javascript.ru/ajax/intro)